# Opencart Error after installing backup Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset

Tags: php, opencart

I get tons of this error:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 205 bytes in /home/xtf/public_html/index.php on line 58

After a failed opencart upgrade atempt, i took all the files from my backup (Working backup) and replaced all files on the server.

I have not done any changes to the data in the MySQL database.

Do anyone have tip on how i can fix this error?

Is there a script i can run?

Line 58`$config->set($result['key'], unserialize($result['value']));`

Comment: what line of code is on line 58?

Comment: $config->set($result['key'], unserialize($result['value']));

Comment: it can be a cache problem. It can also be that $result value ? is not correctly taken over to unserialize.

Comment: can u show $result['value']? check if that value is all correct, no pesky backslashes \  that should not be there etc. sometimes it's really that.